# I lose the constant variables (including id) when using pivot_longer with multiple variables

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyr

I try to reshape the following

| country | region | abc2001 | abc2002 | xyz2001 | xyz2002 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Japan | East Asia | 1 | 2 | 4.5 | 5.5 |

to the following

| country | region | year | abc | xyz |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Japan | East Asia | 2001 | 1 | 4.5 |
| Japan | East Asia | 2002 | 2 | 5.5 |

actually there are five more variables in the same way.

I use the following code:

```r
long <- data %>% pivot_longer(cols = c(-country, -region), names_to = c(".value", "year"), names_pattern = "([^\\.]*)\\.*(\\d{4})")
```

The result is long version of the data except that I lose country and region variables. What do I do wrong? Or how else can I do this better?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may change the regex pattern to match one or more non-digits(`\\D+`) as the first capture group and one or more digits (`\\d+`) as the second one

```
librarytidyr)
pivot_longer(data, cols = c(-country, -region),
    names_to = c(".value", "year"), names_pattern = "(\\D+)(\\d+)")
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 × 5
  country region    year    abc   xyz
  <chr>   <chr>     <chr> <int> <dbl>
1 Japan   East Asia 2001      1   4.5
2 Japan   East Asia 2002      2   5.5
```

#### data

```
data <- structure(list(country = "Japan", region = "East Asia", abc2001 = 1L, 
    abc2002 = 2L, xyz2001 = 4.5, xyz2002 = 5.5), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L))
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** see comments as @akrun noted, here is better regex with lookaround:

`rename_with(., ~str_replace(names(data), "(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)", "\\_"))`

**First answer:**

Here is a version with `names_sep`. The challenge was to add an underscore in the column names. **The preferred answer is that of @akrun**:

- `(.*)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars as many as possible
- `(\\d{4}$)` - Group 2: for digits at the end

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data %>% 
  rename_with(., ~sub("(.*)(\\d{4}$)", "\\1_\\2", names(data))) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c(country, region),
             names_to =c(".value","Year"),
             names_sep ="_"
             )
```

```
  country region    Year    abc   xyz
  <chr>   <chr>     <chr> <int> <dbl>
1 Japan   East Asia 2001      1   4.5
2 Japan   East Asia 2002      2   5.5
```

Comment: You can still do this wihtout adding a delimiter i.e. `(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)` split between the non-digit and digit using regex lookaround